# How to make chartist update on Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, chartist.js

First of all a happy new year to everyone.

I would like to call `update` at `chartist-js`.

`main.js`

```
import Chartist from "chartist";

Vue.prototype.$Chartist = Chartist;
```

`Component.vue`

```
<chart-card
                    :chart-data="performanceUser.data"
                    :chart-options="performanceUser.options"
                    chart-type="Line"
                    data-background-color="green">
            </chart-card>
```

`Component.vue -> methods`

```
getStatsUser(){
      UsersAPI.getUserPerformance(this.users.filters.user.active).then(r => {
        this.performanceUser.data.labels = r.data.labels;
        this.performanceUser.data.series = r.data.series;

        this.$Chartist.update();

      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to do. First, you don't need to patch Vue prototype object with **Chartist** instance. Just import `Chartist` package wherever you need it. Prototype patching is required when you need singleton or stateful construct.

Second, I assume all your chart rendering logic will be inside your `chart-card` component. It will roughly look like:

```
<template>
    <!-- Use vue.js ref to get DOM Node reference -->
    <div class="chart-container" ref="chartNode"></div>
</template>
<script>
import Chartist from 'chartist';

export default {

    // data is an object containing Chart X and Y axes data
    // Options is your Chartist chart customization options
    props: ['data', 'options'],

    // Use of mounted is important.
    // Otherwise $refs will not work
    mounted() {

        if (this.data && this.options) {
            // Reference to DOM Node where you will render chart using Chartist
            const divNode = this.$refs.chartNode;

            // Example of drawing Line chart
            this.chartInstance = new Chartist.Line(divNode, this.data, this.options);
        }

    },

    // IMPORTANT: Vue.js is Reactive framework.
    // Hence watch for prop changes here
    watch: {
        data(newData, oldDate) {
            this.chartInstance.update(newData, this.options);
        },

        options(newOpts) {
            this.chartInstance.update(this.data, newOpts);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Finally, in your calling component, you will have:

```
getStatsUser() {
    UsersAPI.getUserPerformance(this.users.filters.user.active).then(r => {
        // Since component is watching props,
        // changes to `this.performanceUser.data`
        // should automatically update component
        this.performanceUser.data = {
            labels: r.data.labels,
            series: r.data.series
        };
    });
}
```

I hope this gives you an idea of how to build Vue wrapper for Chartist graphs.